# Universal syntax file format?

Tags: python, syntax, editor, text-editor

Hey as a project to improve my programing skills I've begun programing a nice code editor in python to teach myself project management, version control, and gui programming. I was wanting to utilize syntax files made for other programs so I could have a large collection already. I was wondering if there was any kind of universal syntax file format much in the same sense as .odt files. I heard of one once in a forum, it had a website, but I can't remember it now. If not I may just try to use gedit syntax files or geany.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning to do syntax highlighting, check out [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), especially the bit about [lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/).

Since you mentioned Geany, you might want to look at the [Scintilla docs](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html).  (Geany is built upon Scintilla).

You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842809/lexers-vs-parsers) interesting.

Also, be sure to get familiar with the venerable [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what .odt has to do with any of this.

I could see some sort of BNF being able to describe (almost) any syntax: Just run the text and the BNF through a parser, and apply a color scheme to the terminals. You could even get a bit more fancy, since you'd have the syntax tree.

In reality, I think most syntax files take an easier approach, such as regular expressions. This would put then somewhere above regular expressions but not really quite context-free in terms of power.

As for file formats, if you re-use something that exists, then you can just loot and pillage (subject to license agreements) their syntax file data.

Comment: ODT is a standard for documents. Hes looking for a standard for source code syntax. That is the relevance.