# Java determine the amount of function parameters solely based on function string

Tags: java, regex

I want to determine how many parameters (top level) a function has, given the String representation of the function. As an example:

```
(1) assertEquals(verify, actual);
(2) assertEquals("message", actual, verify);
(3) assertEquals(account.addMoney(19, Delivery.fast()).toString(), bank.getAccount(person.getCredentials("basic")).tally(), mock.getData().verify());
```

Answers should be (1) = 2, (2) = 3, (3) = 3.
You may assume I have the function name, e.g. regex on assert.

Basically I can count commas, but I need to take into account function parameters for inner function calls. So

```
function(param1, param2.data(param3, param4, param5.getData(param6, param7));
```

Of course the nesting can be arbitrary deep.

I think a regex might do the trick, but my experience with them is insufficient to solve this question.

Please note that I have considered using a lever/parser, but this seems a bit overkill for my intentions. I have a set of functions as strings and my target method invocations are assertion methods.

Comment: Java regex engine does not support recursion.

Comment: You know, if you really intend to deal with **real** source code ... consider using a **parser**. Or what happens when people start creating array instances, or anonymous inner classes as arguments?

Comment: Perhaps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842809/lexers-vs-parsers can be helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you use reflection, if the function is real function in compiled class.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem you need a [lexical analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages).

The lexical analyzer split the string in tokens

The parse take the tokens and build a data structure, often a tree, that better represents what the tokens means.

Navigating that data structure you can easily found how many parameters there are.

---

Note: this is the same process followed to transform a program written by a human, that is a text file (like a .java file for example) in a different form that can be interpreted by a computer (the process of compiling).

---

Using a lexical analyzer and a parser is necessary to correctly handle strings like the followings:

- `function("a,b", c)`
- `function(new String[]{"a", "b"})`
- `function(a(b, c))`
- `function(',')`

and any composition of them

---

A lexical analyzer using java can be the following [JFlex](http://jflex.de/).

I think that once that you have tokens you can manually count commas and parenthesis (that now are really commas and parenthesis, not part of strings or something other)

Comment: This is indeed an option to solve the problem, but this is a bit overkill for my intentions. I simply have a set of functions of which I have the source (string). My target is assertion method calls, so this simplifies the analysis considerably ;)

Comment: You need to consider that you can have also strings containing the commas, arrays wich elements can be separated by commas. It is not something that can be solved without a parser + lexical analyzer.

Comment: Any suggestions for a light weight Java lexer/parser that takes a String as input? @Davide: hadn't considered all those border cases! Problem seemed simpler at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on possible cases I defined a recursive algorithm to find out the number of function parameters. Please post any corner-cases that break the code below :) Code works for cases (also recursive) as suggested by [Davide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803853/davide-lorenzo-marino)

```
/*
 * returns the number of parameters in this function
 */
private int functionParameters(String function) {
    String fnStripped = stripTill('(', function);
    String fnStripped2 = fnStripped.substring(1);
    // find function with 0 parameters, i.e. ()
    if (removeWhiteSpace(fnStripped).length() == 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    // find function with >= 1 parameters
    return countFunctionParameters(fnStripped2);
}

/*
 * @pre: function is a string, starting from the arguments of a function, excluding the first parenthesis.
 * @pre: function has at least one parameter.
 * @post: the number of parameters of the original (top level) function.
 */
private int countFunctionParameters(String function) {
    // every function has at least one parameter
    if (function.length() == 0) {
        return 1;
    } 
    char next = function.charAt(0);
    String newString = function.substring(1);

    switch(next) {
        case ',' : return 1 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
        case '(' : newString = removeUntil(')', newString); return 0 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
        case '"' : newString = removeUntil('"', newString); return 0 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
        case '\'' : newString = removeUntil('\'', newString); return 0 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
        case '{' : newString = removeUntil('}', newString); return 0 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
        default : return 0 + countFunctionParameters(newString);
    }
}

private String removeUntil(char c, String str) {
    System.out.println("CURRENT: " + str);
    if (str.equals("")) {
        return str;
    }
    String newString = str.substring(1);
    if (str.charAt(0) == c) {
        return newString;
    }

    switch (str.charAt(0)) {
        case '(' : return removeUntil(c, removeUntil('(', newString));
        case '"' : return removeUntil(c, removeUntil('"', newString));
        case '\'' : return removeUntil(c, removeUntil('\'', newString));
        case '{' : return removeUntil(c, removeUntil('}', newString));
        case ')' : return newString;
        case '}' : return newString;
        case '\\' : return removeUntil(c, newString.substring(1)); // disregard the escaped character!
        default : return removeUntil(c, newString);
    }
}

private String removeWhiteSpace(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
}

private String stripTill(char c, String str) {
    while (str.charAt(0) != c) {
        str = str.substring(1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: this is not so simple. If you have for example myFunction("\"", 3); you have some problem for the first string containing a \"

Comment: Good point. I did not yet model escaping characters. They are indeed a bit trickier. For my purpose an approximation might suffice if it captures most cases, which I have to find out. A simple solution here could be to strip away any single character after '\'.