# Is any part of C++ syntax context sensitive?

Tags: c++, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is C++ context-free or context-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589346/is-c-context-free-or-context-sensitive)

This is probably a silly question to people knowledgeable about compilers, but I'm honestly ignorant about the answer.

Is C++ syntax context-sensitive? In other words, is C++ syntax not expressible with context-free grammars?

Obviously C++ *is* parsed with regular parsing tools and that parsing is not particularly ineffective (!), but I do recall reading something about this (I don't remember where) and I thought I'd get my facts straight with the community before spreading lies... Maybe a subset of C++ is CS? Maybe the new spec? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the responses. However, for completeness' sake, what part of compilation deals with the ambiguity? A CFG is a grammar that has only one non-terminal symbol on the left-hand-side of the rule (eg. `A->zC`), a CSG is one that has a terminal (plus a non-terminal) on the left-hand-side (`aAv->QT`), where uppercase letters are nonterminals and lowercase are terminals. Is any representation like the latter in the grammar **parsing** C++ source code?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589346), which got closed as a duplicate, had much better *(and more correct..)* answers.  They should probably be merged...