# Is there a standard C++ grammar?

Tags: c++, standards, grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

Does the standard specify the official C++ grammar?

I searched, but did not find it anywhere.

Also, I wish to read a bit about C++ grammar in detail, like which category of grammars it falls in, etc. Any links pointing me in the right direction would be helpful.

By category, I mean

[image: Click to enlarge]
taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).

Comment: The category is 'horrible mess.'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The grammar is described in detail throughout the standard and is summarized in Appendix A:  Grammar Summary (it's Appendix A in both the C++03 standard and the C++0x final committee draft).

You can [purchase the C++03 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/83763#83763) or you can [download the C++0x FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/) (it's document n3092 on that page).

To answer the "what category is it in?" question, [the C++ grammar is *not* context-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172939/is-any-part-of-c-syntax-context-sensitive) (also see the questions linked in answers to that question; they have additional examples of issues related to the C++ grammar and parsing C++).

Comment: The last SO link is nice. By the way it's now [Is C++ context-free or context-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589346/is-c-context-free-or-context-sensitive)

Answer (score 10):

Alessio Marchetti put a hyperlinked BNF grammar for C++ up at http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/.

Having everything linked together and on a single page makes it easy to navigate between rules.

Comment: Would be nice if it were updated somehwere

Comment: The source says it's updated in 2018, but seems to be pre-c++11 still https://github.com/alx71hub/hcb

Answer (score 6):

Andrew Birkett has a thorough overview of parsing C++ [on his web site](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/).  It covers some of the difficulties in creating a C++ grammar (mixing lexical, syntactic, and semantic analysis) and includes links to several C++ grammars.

Answer (score 2):

Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, wrote a book called The C++ Programming Language which has been updated many times (I read the 3rd edition about 10 years ago). I recall it had very technical details regarding grammar (pre-processor and compiler).

You can probably find this book in on of your local book stores, it may offer you more enjoyment than a standards document from ANSI, depending on how specific you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but as far as I see, James McNellis's link (to the pdf) contains a note on the first page:

> Warning
>
> This document is not an ISO
> International Standard. It is
> distributed for review and comment. It
> is subject to change without notice
> and may not be referred to as an
> International Standard.

So, searched and I think this is the correct link to the official ISO:
[http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/%7Edladams/cxx_standard.pdf)

Comment: The PDF to which I linked is for the final committee draft of the forthcoming C++0x standard; it is the latest version of the next C++ standard, and since it hasn't been completed and ratified, it's not "official." The PDF to which you link is the C++98 standard, to which numerous corrections were made in 2003 to give the C++03 standard; most of the changes were minor, but there were some big changes.  I'm actually somewhat surprised there is a PDF of that freely available; I believe the only way to _legitimately_ get a copy of the ISO standard is by purchasing it (via the link I gave).

Comment: Well then we both learnt something new today - you, that these ISO docs are freely available, and me, that the link you've provided is what I want to keep in my PC (: Thank you!