# Do "else if" exist in c++ or it just only "if" and "else"?

Tags: c++, if-statement

This might not be a problem but just for peace of mind and I think it good to know how c++ mechanic deal with this keyword.
Consider this,

```
if (condition1)statement1;
else if (condition2)statement2;
```

we can interprete as,

```
if (condition1)statement1;
else statement3;
```

where "statement3" is "if (condition2)statement2;"
Which not violate the c++ syntax.

In another case, if we added curly-bracket

```
if (condition1){
    statement1;
}
else if (condition2){
    statement2;
}
```

Which equivalent to

```
if (condition1){
    statement1;
}
else {
    if (condition2){
        statement2;
    }
}
```

Or, if we add more "else if" condition as following.

```
if (condition1){
    statement1;
}
else if (condition2){
    statement2;
}
else if (condition3){
    statement3;
}
else{
        statement4;
}
```

We got

```
if (condition1){
    statement1;
}
else {
    if (condition2){
        statement2;
    }
    else {
        if (condition3){
            statement3;
        }
        else{
            statement4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are statements and code, but I am oblivious to the intended purpose.

Comment: `else if` is always an `else`, followed by an `if`.  If that's your question - it's hard to understand what "[does] _else if_ exist in c++" means.  They exist.

Comment: @DrewDormann but it is interesting that some languages have 'if' 'else' and 'elseif' , python for example.

Comment: @pm100 Indeed, many languages have some `elif` concept.  I'm not smart enough to know why it's necessary in those languages.

Comment: Python has `elif` because, being indentation sensitive, the alternative would involve unwanted indentation (in C++, you simply don't indent the inside of the `else` and it looks fine). Perl has `elsif` because the `{}` on an `else` block are mandatory in Perl, so you can't simply chain the keywords together. Ruby has `elsif` because, erm, I guess they were copying Perl? I don't see any immediate reason why `else if` *wouldn't* work in Ruby.

Comment: For the extreme OCD, each subsequent `else if` would be indented another level.  But in my experience, most OCD folks (myself included) forgive not indenting those in if/else if/else ladder-logic constructs.

Comment: I just found similar post in stack overfloaw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373076/is-else-if-a-single-keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question as asked

> Do "else if" exist in c++ or it just only "if" and "else"?

No, `else if` is not a c++ keyword. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Note the `else statement-false` part. Then your following `if` just becomes that `statement-false`

Comment: Where it becomes a bit interesting for parsers is that the `statement-false` production encompasses both the `if (condition2) statement-true2; else statement-false2;` and not just the `if`.  And gives a sometimes surprising meaning to the tricky sequence `if (condition1) if (condition2) statement-true2; else statement-false2;`  Use braces!