# Whats the best approach to learning logical format and vocabulary needed to read the ISO C++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards

On the ISO website [https://isocpp.org/std/the-standar](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard)d they answer the question **Why is the standard hard to read?**, stating ...

> The standard is not intended to teach how to use C++. Rather, it is an
>   international treaty – a formal, legal, and sometimes mind-numbingly
>   detailed technical document intended primarily for people writing C++
>   compilers and standard library implementations.

They then give a link to some resources where one can learn cpp more easily https://isocpp.org/get-started. This is great, but all resources I can find are geared towards teaching me CPP, when what I want is a resource that helps me learn how to read the standard.

For example, I'm trying to read through ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) (*I use 98 because of work*); And if I want to look up functions I see something like this.

> In a declarationT D where D has the form
>
> D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause) cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>   exception-specification<sub>opt</sub>
>
> and the type of the contained declarator-id in the declaration T D1 is
>   “derived-declaratortype-list T,” thetype of the declarator-id in D is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list function of
>   (parameter-declaration-clause) cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>   returning T”; a type of this form is a function type<sup>86</sup>).

I can look up what the vocabulary words mean and generally fill in what's being conveyed but there's details that aren't straight forward. For example what does the  **<sub>opt</sub>** subscript mean ? Where do I find the rules to how they're using it ? Are there any resources that flesh out these details or at least give an overview that I can reference ?

Comment: fyi might be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849795/is-there-a-standard-c-grammar

Comment: Some details are documented on the GH here (https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/Specification-Style-Guidelines), but yeah, most things aren't documented. Also in your case *opt* => optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard actually provides you with some of tools you need to read it.  [Section 4 General principles](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro) contains a lot of what you need to know before you start reading the rest of it.  For instance, [[syntax]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro#syntax-1) has

> In the syntax notation used in this document, syntactic categories are indicated by *italic* type, and literal words and characters in `constant width` type. Alternatives are listed on separate lines except in a few cases where a long set of alternatives is marked by the phrase “one of”. If the text of an alternative is too long to fit on a line, the text is continued on subsequent lines indented from the first one. An optional terminal or non-terminal symbol is indicated by the subscript “<sub>*opt*</sub>”, so
>
> ```
> { expressionopt }
> ```
>
> indicates an optional expression enclosed in braces.

So it tells you that <sub>*opt*</sub> means optional.

Comment: These are the useful links I've accumulated: General principles -
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro, Style Guidelines -
https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/Specification-Style-Guidelines, Where to find ISO Standards - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents, the ISO website - https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard