# How to efficently build an interpreter (lexer+parser) in C?

Tags: html, c, parsing, interpreter, lexer

I'm trying to make a meta-language for writing markup code (such as xml and html) which can be directly embedded into C/C++ code.
Here is a simple sample written in this language, I call it WDI (Web Development Interface):

```
 /*
  * Simple wdi/html sample source code
  */
 #include <mySite>

 string name = "myName";
 string toCapital(string str);

 html
 {
  head {
   title { mySiteTitle; }
   link(rel="stylesheet", href="style.css");
  }
  body(id="default") {
   // Page content wrapper
   div(id="wrapper", class="some_class") {
    h1 { "Hello, " + toCapital(name) + "!"; }

    // Lists post
    ul(id="post_list") {
     for(post in posts) {
      li { a(href=post.getID()) { post.tilte; } }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Basically it is a modified C source with a user-friendly interface for html.
As you can see the traditional tag-based style is substituted by C-like commands, with blocks delimited by curly braces.
I need to build an interpreter to translate this code to html and posteriorly insert it into C, so that it can be compiled. The C part stays intact.
Inside the wdi source it is not necessary to use prints, every return statement will be used for output (in printf function).
The program's output will be clean html code.

So, for example a heading 1 tag would be transformed like this:

```
h1 { "Hello, " + toCapital(name) + "!"; }
// would become:
printf("<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>", toCapital(name));
```

My main goal is to create an interpreter to translate wdi source to html like this:

`tag(attributes) {content}` => `<tag attributes>content</tag>`

Secondly, html code returned by the interpreter has to be inserted into C code with printfs. Variables and functions that occur inside wdi should also be sorted in order to use them as printf parameters (the case of toCapital(name) in sample source).

I am searching for efficient (I want to create a fast parser) way to create a lexer and parser for wdi. Already tried flex and bison, but as I am not sure if they are the best tools. Are there any good alternatives? What is the best way to create such an interpreter? Can you advise some brief literature on this issue?

Comment: imho, flex and bison are probably the best tools for the job.

Comment: Aren't you really asking for a WDI->C compiler?  It doesn't sound like you want to directly execute WDI code, but rather convert it to C and then feed the C code to a C compiler.

Comment: That's right! WDI should be converted to C. But I think the implementation would be similar, so I also would like to create just an interpreter for html only use and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really serious about this, what you want to do is to modify an existing C parser. The [Edison Design Group C Front End](http://www.edg.com) might be an option, although it *really* wants to be *just* a C (C++) front end.

Another option is our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).  DMS can be obtained with a [C Front End](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) that contains a full C parser driven entirely from a grammar.

DMS provides direct support for building dialects of languages, and what you want to do is build a dialect of C, so it would support your goal.  DMS also provides lots of machinery for building translators, so it would be fairly easy to translate your dialect into real C code and emit it.

Answer (score 3):

bison/flex or yacc/lex is the traditional way to do it.
IMHO, there is nothing better suited to the task at hand.

Note that the task can't be done by a regular language (i.e. regex, simple perl script, etc.), so you really need a parser.

Better to do it right. Most propably, a yacc/bison generated parser will be much cleaner (and faster) than some hand-crafted, recursive descending parser.

Comment: If you are going to parse C (or an extension of it, such as the OP wants), you'll find that bison/yacc/LALR(1) doesn't handle this very well. C compiler parsers are mostly awful hacks where the parsing machinery is tangled with name resolution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-c-cannot-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737 for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest this tutorial: http://www.icemanind.com

There is a tutorial there on how to write your own virtual machine, complete with an assembler and interpreter

Answer (score 1):

[Boost spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) may be better than bison/flex for such purposes.

Comment: Have you ever used it? How about performance? Is it good compared to flex and bison? I have already started doig it with flex and bison, so I have to be sure it is worth to move to boost's spirit.

Comment: performance is really good. Compilation times are slow though.