# Why won't Parsec consider the right-hand side of my <|> alternative?

Tags: haskell, lexical-analysis, parsec

I’m trying to parse C++ code. Therefore, I need a context-sensitive lexer. In C++, `>>` is either one or two tokens (`>>` or `>` `>`), depending on the context. To make it even more complex, there is also a token `>>=` which is always the same regardless of the context.

```
punctuation :: Bool -> Parser Token
punctuation expectDoubleGT = do
    c <- oneOf "{}[]#()<>%;:.+-*/^&|~!=,"
    case c of
        '>' ->
            (char '=' >> return TokGTEq) <|>
            if expectDoubleGT
                then (string ">=" >> return TokRShiftEq) <|> return TokGT
                else (char '>' >> ((char '=' >> return TokRShiftEq) <|> return TokRShift)) <|> return TokGT
```

When `expectDoubleGT` is `False`, this function works fine. However, when `expectDoubleGT` is `True` (the second last line above), it gives an error when the input is `>>`.

```
*Parse> parseTest (punctuation True) ">"
TokGT
*Parse> parseTest (punctuation True) ">>="
TokRShiftEq
*Parse> parseTest (punctuation True) ">>"
parse error at (line 1, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting ">="
```

Why does the expression `(string ">=" >> return TokRShiftEq) <|> return TokGT` raise an error rather than returning `TokGT` when the input is `>`? (the first `>` was already consumed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parsec only tries the second parser in

```
p1 <|> p2
```

if `p1` failed without consuming any input. On The input `">>"`, after the first `'>'` has been consumed,

```
string ">="
```

fails after consuming the left over `'>'`, so the second parser isn't used.

You need a `try`

```
try (string ">=" >> return TokRShiftEq)
```

there so that if `string ">="` fails, no input is consumed and the alternative parser is used.

Answer (score -1):

Use `libclang`. It can parse all of C++. No matter how hard you try, you won't be able to.

Comment: While this isn't a good answer to the question, it is a useful comment. Parsing C and C++ means you [should locally accept ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172342/complexity-of-parsing-c), and I'm not sure whether Parsec can do that.