# Java parser written in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, compilation

I'm looking for implementation of Java source code parser written in JavaScript language. Do you know any?

Comment: For what purpose? Interpreting the code and running it? Colorizing it in HTML? Mapping it into a JSON object?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jeff In the result I would like to have some kind of Abstract Syntax Tree.

Comment: @Rocket I'm interested in it for educational purpose. First of all I want to estimate modern JavaScript engines abilities in parsing language with strict type system.

Comment: I don't think I've seen one.  I've seen syntax highlighters, but never parsers.

Comment: @Eliah: What has a "strict type system" got to do with *parsing*?   You might wish to parse, as one step, and and then do name and type resolution on the resulting AST.  You're not going to do N&T *during* parsing.   ... And, why is the capability of JavaScript wrt N&T interesting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which can have Javascript as a target, with the Java 1.5 grammar at http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g

Edit: link stopped working - try https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4 :)

Comment: Hm... Good idea! Thank you, Chris. But, I'm not sure that the performance of such parser would be enough for parsing large amounts of source codes.

Comment: ok. This is not the solution which I expected, but currently it is only solution which solves this problem.

Comment: @Eliah:  "... not sure ... large amounts of source codes "   ANTLR produces pretty efficient parsers in general.  (My personal bet would be for it, rather than against it.)   I suspect the only way to actually find out is  produce such a parser and try it.   And if you are concerned, why not do this using Java or C++?

Answer (score 5):

Here is Java 1.7 parser http://mazko.github.io/jsjavaparser/ using PEG grammar by Roman R Redziejowski http://www.romanredz.se/Mouse/Java.1.7.peg

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a Java parser *per se*, but here are some parser generators for Javascript:

- http://jscc.jmksf.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/cruiser/wiki/Parse
- http://pegjs.majda.cz/
- http://zaach.github.com/jison/
- and more are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) including PGS's that are written in other languages and target Javascript ...

If is one of these is ready for prime-time, you should be able to translate the grammar for Java into the requisite form and then use the PGS's to generate a Java parser in Javascript.

Of course, that will only give you a parser.  If you want to do type analysis (as your comment seems to be saying), that's not what a parser does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Stephen. I was working with some of these parser generators. I think its performance is not good enough for parsing large amounts of code with C++ like syntax(like Java), unfortunatelly.

Comment: @Eliah - it might seem counter-intuitive, but generated parsers tend to be faster than hand written parsers, especially if the PGS is mature.

Comment: I noticed that ANTLR will also generate parsers in Javascript.

Comment: @Eliah:  You seem concerned about parsing complex ("C++-like") syntax.  What specific syntax concerns you, and why do you think a modern parser generator can't handle it?  (C++ is in a league by itself and does give modern parser generators real trouble, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737 but Java is not C++).

Answer (score -3):

Try the **[Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino)** engine?

Comment: The OP is looking for the other way around.

Comment: Rhino solves opposite problem: it parses JavaScript in Java environment.