# Parsing Java Classnames From Source File using Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, scala, parsing

Given a source file (Java / Scala), how do I parse out the class name of the source file using Javascript?

Specifically, user enters source code into a browser-based editor.  I would like to parse out the class names from the source text.

For example:

```
var sourceText = 

     class TestClass extends MyClass{
    // do something
    }



      class
       TestClass2
       extends
       MyParentClass2 
    {

    }

class TestClass3 
extends MyParentClass3 { }
```

How do I write this function:

```
parseClassNameFromSourceText: function (sourceText) {

}
```

such that if I passed in the above source text, it will produce [TestClass, TestClass2, TestClass3]?

Comment: How do you want inner classes and anonymous inner classes handled?

Answer (score 0):

You titled this "regex", but there's no way you're going to parse this out with regex.  You have to write a proper (if simple) parser.  Here are a few things that will trip you up:

```
// class Foo is imaginary
/* class Bar is just an idea */
class Baz {
  public class Quux {
    public String uhoh() { return "I am an inner class YIKES can you parse strings?!"; }
  }
}
class /* comments can go here you know! */ Bippy {}
```

And a few Scala-specific ones:

```
class Wimble {
  val `class YouMustBeJoking` = "Actually, I am a legal identifier!"
  val moreProblems = """class is always okay in strings"""
  def tricky = s"${class Glath { def iAmARealClass = true }}"
}
```

A full parser for Java is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993769).  You may be able to extend it to parse Scala well enough for these purposes (depending on what you decide about inner classes).