# Are GCC and Clang parsers really handwritten?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, compilation

It seems that GCC and LLVM-Clang are using **handwritten recursive descent parsers**, and **not** machine generated, Bison-Flex based, bottom up parsing.

Could someone here please confirm that this is the case?
And if so, why do mainstream compiler frameworks use handwritten parsers?

**Update** : [interesting blog on this topic here](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/09/ll-and-lr-in-context-why-parsing-tools.html)

Comment: Almost all the mainstream compilers are using handwritten parsers. What's a problem with that?

Comment: you have to do it (semi-) manually if you need performance.

Comment: And not only performance - better error messages, ability to recover, etc.

Comment: What about MS VisualStudio? though not open-sourced, could someone from MS verify that they too are using a hand written recursive descent parser?

Comment: @GeneBushuyev, from the GCC wiki: "...Although **timings showed a 1.5% speedup**, the main benefits are facilitating of future enhancements ..." this speedup seems rather marginal ...

Comment: Why is this surprising? Even my recursive command line parser is hand written...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes:

- GCC used a yacc (bison) parser once upon a time, but it was replaced with a hand-written recursive descent parser at some point in the 3.x series: see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/New_C_Parser for links to relevant patch submissions.
- Clang also uses a hand-written recursive descent parser: see the section "A single unified parser for C, Objective C, C++ and Objective C++" near the end of http://clang.llvm.org/features.html .

Comment: Does that mean that ObjC, C and C++ has LL(k) Grammars?

Comment: No: even C, the simplest of the three, has an ambiguous grammar.  For example, `foo * bar;` could parse as either a multiplication expression (with the result unused), or a declaration of a variable `bar` with type pointer-to-`foo`.  Which one is correct depends on whether a `typedef` for `foo` is in scope at the time, which is not something that can be determined with any amount of lookahead.  But that just means that the recursive descent parser needs some ugly extra machinery added to handle that.

Comment: I can confirm from empirical evidence, that C++11, C, and Objective C have context free grammars that a GLR parser can handle.

Comment: Regarding context sensitiveness, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14589567/1959808) claims neither: that parsing these languages is likely Turing-complete.

Answer (score 121):

There's a folk-theorem that says C is hard to parse, and C++ essentially impossible.

**It isn't true.**

What is true is that C and C++ are pretty hard to parse using LALR(1) parsers without hacking the parsing machinery and tangling in symbol table data.   GCC in fact used to parse them, using YACC and additional hackery like this, and yes it was ugly.  *Now GCC uses handwritten parsers, but still with the symbol table hackery. The Clang folks never tried to use automated parser generators; AFAIK the Clang parser has always been hand-coded recursive descent.*

What is true, is that C and C++ are relatively easy to parse with stronger automatically generated parsers, e.g., [GLR parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser), and you don't need any hacks.   The [Elsa](http://www.scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/) C++ parser is one example of this.  Our [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) is another (as are all our "compiler" front ends, GLR is pretty wonderful parsing technology).

Our C++ front end isn't as fast as GCC's, and certainly slower than Elsa; we've put little energy into tuning it carefully because we have other more pressing issues (nontheless it has been used on millions of lines of C++ code).   Elsa is likely slower than GCC simply because it is more general.  Given processor speeds these days, these differences might not matter a lot in practice.

But the "real compilers" that are widely distributed today have their roots in compilers of 10 or 20 years ago or more.   Inefficiencies then mattered much more, and nobody had heard of GLR parsers, so people did what they knew how to do.  Clang is certainly more recent, but then folk theorems retain their "persuasiveness" for a long time.

You don't have to do it that way anymore.   You can very reasonably use GLR and other such parsers as front ends, with an improvement in compiler maintainability.

What *is* true, is that getting a grammar that matches your friendly neighborhood compiler's behavior is hard.  While virtually all C++ compilers implement (most) of the original standard, they also tend have lots of dark corner extensions, e.g., DLL specifications in MS compilers, etc.   If you have a strong parsing engine, you can
spend your time trying to get the final grammar to match reality, rather than trying to bend your grammar to match the limitations of your parser generator.

EDIT November 2012:  Since writing this answer, we've improved our C++ front end to handle full C++11, including ANSI, GNU, and MS variant dialects.  While there was lots of extra stuff, we don't have to change our parsing engine; we just revised the grammar rules.  We *did* have to change the semantic analysis; C++11 is semantically very complicated, and this work swamps the effort to get the parser to run.

EDIT February 2015:  ... now handles full C++14. (See [get human readable AST from c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388771/get-human-readable-ast-from-c-code/17393852#17393852) for GLR parses of a simple bit of code, and C++'s infamous "most vexing parse").

EDIT April 2017:   Now handles (draft) C++17.

Comment: PostScript:  Just as getting the grammar to match what the vendors really do is harder, get name and type resolution to match the different vendor's interpretation of the C++11 manual is even harder, because the only evidence you have are programs that compile slightly differently, if you can find them.  We're largely past that as of Aug 2013 for C++11 proper, but I despair a little at the C++ committee which seems hell-bent on producing an even larger (and from experience, more confusing) standard in the form of C++1y.

Comment: I’d really like to know: How do you handle that `foo * bar;` ambiguity?

Comment: @Martin: our parser parses it *both* ways, producing a tree containing special "ambiguity nodes" whose children are the alternative parses; the children do maximal sharing of their children so we end up with a DAG instead of a tree.   *After* parsing completes, we run an attribute grammar evaluator (AGE) over the DAG (fancy name for "walk the tree and do stuff" if you don't know it) which computes the types of all declared identifiers.  ...

Comment: ... The ambiguous children can't both be type-consistent; the  AGE on discovering an ambiguous child that cannot be sensibly typed simply deletes it.  What is left are the well-typed children; thus, we have determined which parse of "foo*bar;" is correct.  This trick works for all kinds of crazy ambiguities found in the real grammars we build for the real dialects of C++11, and *completely* separates parsing from semantic analysis for names.  This clean separation means lots less engineering work to do (no tangles to debug).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1004737/120163 for more discussion.

Comment: If you want to see a tree with ambiguity nodes, this page shows an Oberon grammar and parse tree with a few ambiguity nodes: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSParsers.html

Comment: C++ is bloody hard to parse, and I *would* say it's essentially impossible. Search for "Turing-complete semantic predicates" in this page (about 2/3rds down): http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/09/ll-and-lr-in-context-why-parsing-tools.html ; the link in that list item is also relevant.

Comment: @TimČas: What are you trying to say?  Yes, you can probably write programs that no compiler can actually parse, esp. if you use templates to encode algorithms with enormously long runtime.  To the extent that C++ is parseable in practice, there are compilers that do it, and tools like ours that do it.   Beyond this practical extent nobody cares.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I think the fact that, for N different compilers, C++ is parsed (and compiled) in N different ways because of its complexity, states that there *ARE* problems. And I can guarantee you that the people who run into these bugs do care; they've just spent hours of their life [if they're lucky] trying to debug a program that didn't have a problem (their compiler did).

Comment: @TimCas: You seem to be confusing "bugs in the implementation" with "impossible to parse".  We'll agree the standard is complicated, and even probably broken in many dark corners.  Have you checked Java standard/compilers recently?  (Have you looked at PHP at all???) Can you exhibit any specific compiler (even non-C++) that has no bugs in it? *What is your point?*

Comment: @IraBaxter: I'm not mixing them up. I'm just replying to your comment: "To the extent that C++ is parseable in practice, there are compilers that do it, and tools like ours that do it. Beyond this practical extent nobody cares.". People do care when parsing is so complicated (almost?) nobody gets it right.

Comment: @TimCas: Tell that to the C++ committee.  And, to every other language standards committee, and compiler implementers.  NONE OF THEM ARE PERFECT.  NOBODY GETS IT RIGHT. So what?

Comment: @TimCas:  Actually, I'm with you on railing at the apparant stupidity of designing language syntax (and semantics) that are so complicated that is is so hard to get it right (yes, C++ language suffers here badly).  I wish language design committees would design syntax so simpler parsing technologies would work, and explicitly define the language semantics and check it with some semantic analysis tools.  Alas, the world doesn't seem to be like that.  So, I take the view that you build what you have to build as well as you can, and get on with life, in spite of the awkwardness.

Comment: @IraBaxter: There isn't much choice regarding "dealing with it", now is there? My only argument is that parsing C++ *is* essentially impossible. I've provided examples of why it is so; you somehow seem to agree with me on that, and yet you end up being *very* aggressive in disagreement. I've provided very clear examples of C++ parsing issues, which show why it's *essentially* impossibly to do right (and *actually* impossible to do at all without a turing-complete parser). *Quod erat demonstrandum.*

Comment: Clang uses a hand-written parser partly because it's easy to reuse the same core for C, C++, *and* Objective C, and partly because they're trying to support virtually everything out there, from MSVC's extensions to GCC extensions to their own custom extensions and allow them all to be individually enabled via command-line arguments.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: One can do that just fine with grammars.  We use a grammar-based approach because its easy to reuse the same grammar for C (in all of its dialects) *and* Objective C, and C++ with MSVC's extensions to GCC extensions as well as our own custom extensions.  Which language/dialect we use for a specific tool is individually enabled by tool-generation time command-line arguments so we don't pay a runtime cost checking for all the alternative dialects when the generated tools runs.  And our dev team is LOT smaller than Clangs.

Comment: @IraBaxter how does the advertisement for your company's products enhance this answer?

Comment: Adverstisement? The motivating question is about whether one can write a parser for C or C++ with parser generators, and mentions a variety of front end tools that do not. Surely that is obvious.   This answer shows that one can do it well and produce production tools; many readers think this is interesting based on the vote count.  How does your objection to the fact that the tool happens to be commercial improve this discussion?

Comment: Custom hand-written parsers allow to produce much more sensible errors/warnings. This was always a weak suit for parser generators (which usually can only spew something like "expected ; but found foo" unhelpful errors until specifically massaged).

Comment: @DanM: That's the usual excuse for custom parsers.   What I think this really means is that people that hand build such parsers spend more energy trying to produce good error messages, whereas people that use parser generators, and don't understand how they work/aren't willing to enhance it help with error diagnostics,  simply blow off the extra work.   Its one man's opinion, but I think it is laziness on the part of parser generator users.  See my comment on Doug's answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter some errors require more semantic knowledge, not just syntax/parser one. Also, if the effort it requires to maintain good diagnostics for generated and handwritten parsers are comparable, when why bother? I've yet to see a parser generator that'd make it easy without becoming an expert in it. I mean it can be explained as laziness. GCC maintainers were lazy. Programmers were lazy. It's what drives IT.

Comment: @IraBaxter **10 years latter with i7 32 GB RAM and large SSD compile-time performance still matters.** At least with Visual Studio, in a medium size project, one can easily make massive changes such that IntelliSense is not able to keep up. As a comparison, compilation of C# code is at least 10 times faster while the final application has similar performance.

Answer (score 36):

Clang's parser is a hand-written recursive-descent parser, as are several other open-source and commercial C and C++ front ends.

Clang uses a recursive-descent parser for several reasons:

- **Performance**: a hand-written parser allows us to write a fast parser, optimizing the hot paths as needed, and we're always in control of that performance. Having a fast parser has allowed Clang to be used in other development tools where "real" parsers are typically not used, e.g., syntax highlighting and code completion in an IDE.
- **Diagnostics and error recovery**: because you're in full control with a hand-written recursive-descent parser, it's easy to add special cases that detect common problems and provide great diagnostics and error recovery (e.g., see http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#expressivediags) With automatically generated parsers, you're limited to the capabilities of the generator.
- **Simplicity**: recursive-descent parsers are easy to write, understand, and debug. You don't need to be a parsing expert or learn a new tool to extend/improve the parser (which is especially important for an open-source project), yet you can still get great results.

Overall, for a C++ compiler, it just doesn't matter much: the parsing part of C++ is non-trivial, but it's still one of the easier parts, so it pays to keep it simple. Semantic analysis---particularly name lookup, initialization, overload resolution, and template instantiation---is orders of magnitude more complicated than parsing. If you want proof, go check out the distribution of code and commits in Clang's "Sema" component (for semantic analysis) vs. its "Parse" component (for parsing).

Comment: Yes, semantic analysis is harder by a lot. We have some 4000 lines of grammar rules that comprise our C++11 grammar, and some 180,000 lines of attribute grammar code for the "semantic analyses" Doub lists above, with another 100,000 lines of supporting code. Parsing really isn't the problem, although it is hard enough if you start on the wrong foot.

Comment: I'm not so sure that hand-written parsers are *necessarily* better for error reporting/recovery.   It does appear that people have put more energy into such parsers than into enhancing parsers produced by automatic parser generators in practice.  There seems to be pretty good research on the topic; this particular paper has really caught my eye: M.G. Burke, 1983, A practical method for LR and LL syntactic error diagnosis and recovery, PhD thesis, Department of Computer Science, New York University, See https://archive.org/details/practicalmethodf00burk

Comment: ... continuing this thought train: if you are willing to modify/extend/customize your hand-built parser to check for special cases for better diagnosis, then you should be willing to make equal investment in better diagnoses of a mechanically generated parser.  For any special parse that you can encode for the manual one, you can code a check for the mechanical one, too  (and for (G)LR parsers, you can pretty much do this as semantic checks on reductions).  To the extent that seems unappetizing, one is just being lazy but that's not an indictment of the mechanically generated parsers IMHO.

Comment: @IraBaxter I would be really glad if you could share some of the resources with us about `writing a decent parser by hand in C`.

Comment: If you want to build toys, that's an OK path.  Its workable for real languages but parser generators are really the right way to handle complex grammars; I've made that point already in another answer to this question.  If you want to write recursive descent parsers, another of my SO answers tells you how to do it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163  Price: You get to deal with the complicated cases that parser generators handle for you.

Answer (score 10):

Weird answers there!

C/C++ grammars aren't context free. They are context sensitive because of the Foo * bar; ambiguity. We have to build a list of typedefs to know if Foo is a type or not.

Ira Baxter: I don't see the point with your GLR thing. Why build a parse tree which comprises ambiguities. Parsing means solving ambiguities, building the syntax tree. You resolve these ambiguities in a second pass, so this isn't less ugly. For me it is far more ugly ...

Yacc is a LR(1) parser generator (or LALR(1)), but it can be easily modified to be context sensitive. And there is nothing ugly in it. Yacc/Bison has been created to help in parsing C language, so probably it isn't the ugliest tool to generate a C parser ...

Until GCC 3.x the C parser is generated by yacc/bison, with typedefs table built during parsing. With "in parse" typedefs table building, C grammar becomes locally context free and furthermore "locally LR(1)".

Now, in Gcc 4.x, it is a recursive descent parser. It is exactly the same parser as in Gcc 3.x, it is still LR(1), and has the same grammar rules. The difference is that the yacc parser has been hand rewritten, the shift/reduce are now hidden in the call stack, and there is no "state454 : if (nextsym == '(') goto state398" as in gcc 3.x yacc's parser, so it is easier to patch, handle errors and print nicer messages, and to perform some of the next compiling steps during parsing. At the price of much less "easy to read" code for a gcc noob.

Why did they switched from yacc to recursive descent? Because it is quite necessary to avoid yacc to parse C++, and because GCC dreams to be multi language compiler, i.e. sharing maximum of code between the different languages it can compile. This is why the C++ and the C parser are written in the same way.

C++ is harder to parse than C because it isn't "locally" LR(1) as C, it is not even LR(k).
Look at `func<4 > 2>` which is a template function instantiated with 4 > 2, i.e. `func<4 > 2>`
has to be read as `func<1>`. This is definitely not LR(1). Now consider, `func<4 > 2 > 1 > 3 > 3 > 8 > 9 > 8 > 7 > 8>`. This is where a recursive descent can easily solve ambiguity, at the price of a few more function calls (parse_template_parameter  is the ambiguous parser function. If parse_template_parameter(17tokens) failed, try again parse_template_parameter(15tokens), parse_template_parameter(13tokens) 
... until it works).

I don't know why it wouldn't be possible to add into yacc/bison recursive sub grammars, maybe this will be the next step in gcc/GNU parser development?

Comment: "for me, it is far more ugly". What I can tell you is that engineering of a production quality parser using GLR and delay ambiguity resolution is practical with a really small team.  All the other solutions I have seen have involved years of gnashing teeth in public over the backflips and hacks required to make it work with LR, recursive descent, you name it.  You can postulate lots of other cool new parsing technologies, but as far as I can tell, that's just more gnashing of teeth at this point. Ideas are cheap; execution is dear.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Rats! http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.925.5298&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @Fizz:  Interesting paper on parsing Fortress, a complex scientific programming langauge.  They said several things of note: a) classic parser generators (LL(k), LALR(1)) can't handle tough grammars, b) they tried GLR, had troubles with scale but the developers were inexperienced so they didn't complete [that isn't GLR's fault] and c) they used a backtracking (transactional) Packrat parser and put a lot of effort into it including work to produce better error messages.  Regarding their example of parsing    "{|x||x←mySet,3|x}", I beleive GLR would do it just fine and it doesn't need spaces.

Comment: `func<4 > 2>` is not `func<1>`. That code does not compile. The first `>` close the template.

Answer (score 9):

[gcc's parser is handwritten.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c). I suspect the same for clang. This is probably for a few reasons:

- **Performance**: something that you've hand-optimized for your particular task will almost always perform better than a general solution. Abstraction usually has a performance hit
- **Timing**: at least in the case of GCC, GCC predates a lot of free developer tools (came out in 1987). There was no free version of yacc, etc. at the time, which I'd imagine would've been a priority to the people at the FSF.

This is probably not a case of "not invented here" syndrome, but more along the lines of "there was nothing optimized specifically for what we needed, so we wrote our own".

Comment: No free version of yacc in 1987? I think there were free versions when yacc was first delivered under Unix back in the 70s.  And IIRC (other poster seems the same), GCC *used* to have a YACC-based parser.  I heard the excuse for changing it was to get better error reporting.

Comment: I'd like to add it's often easier to generate good error messages from a handwritten parser.

Comment: Your point on Timing is inaccurate. GCC used to have YACC based parser, but this was replaced with a handwritten recursive descent parser, later on.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that GCC and LLVM-Clang are using handwritten recursive descent parsers, and not machine generated, Bison-Flex based, bottom up parsing.

Bison in particular I don't think can handle the grammar without parsing some things ambiguously and doing a second pass later.

I know Haskell's Happy allows for monadic (i.e. state-dependent) parsers that can resolve the particular issue with C syntax, but I know of no C parser generators that allow a user-supplied state monad.

In theory, error recovery would be a point in favor of a handwritten parser, but my experience with GCC/Clang has been that the error messages are not particularly good.

As for performance - some of the claims seem unsubstantiated. Generating a big state machine using a parser generator should result in something that's `O(n)` and I doubt parsing is the bottleneck in much tooling.

Comment: This question already has a very high quality answer, what you are trying to add?