# How are Clang's lexer and parser generated?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I wanted to have a look at LLVM/Clang internals (since I need it for my thesis). I need to work on LLVM, but due to curiosity, I wanted to explore also Clang's codebase.

One thing I couldn't figure out is how are Clang's lexer and parser generated. Are they built using a generator, like Flex/GNU Bison, or ANTLR? Are they hand coded? If yes, are all LLVM based compilers written in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `git log` for the file that interests you; the commit comments usually tell. If they're "reran byacc", byacc was used. In this case I'd guess that you'll find the file was handwritten. Good compilers used for production work often have handwritten lexers, parsers or both.

Comment: As far as I am aware, nothing in LLVM says that you must - or can’t - use a parser generator - it’s up to you.

Comment: More useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319086/are-gcc-and-clang-parsers-really-handwritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang's (preprocessor and) lexer and parser are hand-written, with a bit of help from macros and TableGen files that reduce some of the boilerplate. The [frontend internal manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-lexer-and-preprocessor-library) might provide some more detailed info.

As far as I understand, LLVM-based compilers can choose to implement their lexer and parser in whatever way they want.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the [sources](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/), you can see proper formatting (that's easy for a parser generator to do, but things like hard wrapping just make it look handcoded), as well as many explanatory comments and TODOs. As for all LLVM based compilers, that's very hard to define: anyone could write a compiler which uses LLVM, so surely not *all*.