# Using first-set in recursive descent parser

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I'm writing a recursive descent parser for C in C++. I don't know how to choose the right production in the following case:

```
statement: labeled-statement | compound-statement | expression-statement | selection-statement | iteration-statement | jump-statement
```

I read about the "first"-set which compares the lookahead-token/char with possible terminals which comes first in the productions. Currently I'm stuck at using a first-set in a recursive descent parser, because I only have a function and nothing else, no object for each rule or anything else with which I can identify a rule/production.

Comment: Something up with your shift key?

Comment: No, sry. Next time i'll use it :)

Comment: Thanks! It just keeps the place looking tidy, and it's a small courtesy to those who are going to be helping you out.

Comment: For C, you won't succeed with pure recursive descent (LL(1)) parsing. You need to be able to distinguish certain types in orer to parse this way.  See this answer as to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-c-cannot-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar is invalid for recursive descent parsers because it's ambiguous on the left side:

- `labeled-statement` starts with an identifier
- `compound-statement` starts with a `{` (this is fine)
- `expression-statement` starts with an identifier or a number (or `(`)

Can stop here, you have a clash between labeled statement and expression statement. You need to transform your grammer to get rid of left-side ambiguities (through temporary grammar nodes to contain the common parts so when you branch you can determine which branch to go to using only the look-ahead).

Comment: mhh sounds good, but what about trying one production after another and excluding these, which doesn't match with its "first"-set (for increased performance). if any production fails, i can backtrack to the last production or last valid state?

btw: after i eliminated the left-side ambiguities, i still don't know which production to choose, because i still have no first-set to compare with the lookahead. are there also any good solutions?

Comment: A backtracking compiler will never work because of its insanely low performance for even small input files. Assuming you really did remove the left-side ambiguities, building the first set is easy (if tedious): just go down the productions for every branch and build a set of the first letters possible. For example, `statement`'s first set is `identifier` (from the expressions and labels), `{` (from the compound statement), `number` (expressions), `goto`, `for`, `if` etc. In your recursive function you just check the lookahead against each branch's first set.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, having *any* overlap at all between branches of a single production means your grammar is ambiguous. Also epsilon productions have no place in a recursive descent parser's grammar, you have to get rid of them if you have any.

Comment: Fine :), how can I implement a first-set in c++ code? Where to store the different first-sets and so on? How can I prevent from empty productions, because they are generated by eliminating left-recursions :(.

Comment: They're implemented as simply an array of token types, and you store them as local variables in the recursive functions. And to remove epsilon productions, just google for a nice algorithm, I don't have my dragon book with me and it's been a good 10 years since I last implemented a compiler.

Comment: Very big thanks :). I'll try it tomorrow. Which language did your compiler implement?

Comment: I last implemented a subset of C++ complete with recursion and subclassing for my end of the semester project.