# Linear-time general parser

Tags: parsing, time

I've been reading Dick Grune's Parsing techniques 1st edition for quite a while now, the book is from the mid-90's and the author argues that no such parsing method (Linear-time general parsing) has been discovered until the date.

> "we should like to have a linear-time general parsing method.
>   Unfortunately no such method has been discovered to date." pg 76

Has anyone developed such method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such method has been devised. As far as I can tell, the [CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) remains the general parsing algorithm with the best *worst case* performance (*O(n<sup>3</sup>)*).

Answer (score 1):

A [GLR parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) are O(n^3) in worst case, but offer linear performance where the grammar is deterministic.  Many grammars have this property, so in effect you get linear time parsing in practice.

We've managed to build [parsers for many real, complicated languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds) using a GLR parser, [even the famously hard to parse C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1004737/120163).

Answer (score 0):

[Packrat](http://bford.info/packrat/) with a full memoisation is a guaranteed O(n), but there is a relatively big linear multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a parser (JoeSon) written in CoffeeScript, and I believe it is O(n) for most interesting grammars.

I think it is essentially a Packrat parser, but with the ability to bypass the cache for some rules, which I think is necessary to write whitespace-sensitive grammars.

Packrat does not parse all context free grammars. It has difficulty with counting problems, like with the grammar ' S = x S x | x '. But these kinds of grammars are also difficult for humans to parse.

https://github.com/jaekwon/joeson/blob/master/joeson_grammar.coffee
https://github.com/jaekwon/joeson/blob/master/joescript_grammar.coffee