# Parse Python Code using PyParsing?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, pyparsing, bnf

I'm trying to write PyParsing code capable of parsing any Python code (I know that the AST module exists, but that will just be a starting point - I ultimately want to parse more than just Python code.)

Anyways, I figure I'll just start by writing something able to parse the classic

```
print("Hello World!")
```

So here's what I wrote:

```
from pyparsing import (alphanums, alphas, delimitedList, Forward,
                       quotedString, removeQuotes, Suppress, Word)

expr = Forward()
string = quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
call = expr + Suppress('(') + Optional(delimitedList(expr)) + Suppress(')')
name = World(alphas + '_', alphanums + '_')
expr <<= string | name | call

test = 'print("Hello World!")'
print(expr.parseString(test))
```

When I do that, though, it just spits out:

```
['print']
```

Which is technically a valid `expr` - you can type that into the REPL and there's no problem parsing it, even if it's useless.

So I thought maybe what I would want is to flip around `name` and `call` in my `expr` definition, so it would prefer returning `call`s to `name`s, like this:

```
expr <<= string | call | name
```

Now I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. That makes sense, too:

1. Checks if it's an `expr`.

   1. Checks if it's a `string`, it's not.
   2. Checks if it's a `call`.

      1. It must start with an `expr`, return to start of outer list.

So my question is... how can I define `call` and `expr` so that I don't end up with an infinite recursion, but also so that it doesn't just stop when it sees the name and ignore the arguments?

Is Python code too complicated for PyParsing to handle? If not, is there any limit to what PyParsing can handle?

(Note - I've included the general tags [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing), [abstract-syntax-tree](/questions/tagged/abstract-syntax-tree), and [bnf](/questions/tagged/bnf), because I suspect this is a general recursive grammar definition problem, not something necessarily specific to [pyparsing](/questions/tagged/pyparsing).)

Comment: My guess is that your code is failing to consume terminals and so will parse the same token over and over leading to infinite recursion. I don't know pyparsing, but this [sample of a Python parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/pythonGrammarParser.py/30100174/pythonGrammarParser.py) on the PyParsing home page does consume parsed terminals.

Comment: Parsing of arbitrary ("more than just Python") source code is actually hard; you have to deal with many, many issues, the least of which is what atoms compose your language.   Once you "parse" something, then you will not have enough to do much useful in practice.   See my bio on "Life After Parsing" (which talks about the parsing issues, too).

Comment: @IraBaxter - Your Life after Parsing assumes I want to do more complicated things than I do. I'm looking to write tools to go back and forth between ASTs and Strings - nothing more. I don't want to do any sort of analysis of it. Further, I'll need to distribute everything in source form for free - I'm not buying your product no matter how perfectly it does what I need.

Comment: I'm not asking you to buy my product.   I'm making the point to doing sophisticated tasks with code requires more "ASTs and strings".  (There being little point in only going back and forth between ASTs and strings, what exactly are you doing that requires nothing more than that, for multiple languages?).  You are welcome to achieve that "more sophistication" any way you like including building it all from scratch, or contributing to some other open source solution.    I will suggest this is a lot harder than you seem to think.

Comment: Even if you stick to just "ASTs and strings", the problem is still very hard for modern languages and it isn't getting easier.  See for example,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737   And I would be suprrised if your intentions are limited to just those languages that are "easy" to parse.

Comment: @IraBaxter - I'm looking to build a new language with Python as its basis. My language is a superset of Python (that is, all valid Python code is valid code in my language). I parse it into the AST for my language. Then my AST knows how to transform itself into equivalent Python AST, and then it compiles down into .pyc Python bytecode files. I've already dealt with the my AST -> Python AST problems, plus the Python AST -> .pyc bytecode file problems - the only bridge left to cross is parsing my code into my AST.

Comment: So you are trying to build a translator from your custom dialect to pure Python.  Unless that translation is dead trivial everywhere, you'll need something more than just an AST.   My experience.  Good luck.

Comment: I borrowed your question (with citation) as an example of a left-recursive parser in the next Pyparsing release, which supports left recursion. You can find it here: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/left_recursion.py

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar is left recursive: `expr` expects a `call` which expects an `expr` which expects a `call`... If PyParsing can't handle left recursion, you need to change the grammar to something that PyParsing can work with.

One approach to remove *direct* left recursion is to change a gramar rule such us:

```
A = A b | c
```

into

```
A = c b*
```

In your case, left recursion is *indirect*: it doesn't happen in `expr`, but in a sub rule (`call`):

```
E = C | s | n
C = E x y z
```

To remove indirect left recursion you usually "lift" the definition of the sub-rule to the main rule. Unfortunatelly this removes the offending sub rule from the grammar -- in other words, you lose some structural expressiveness when you do that.

The previous example, with indirect recursion removed, would look like this:

```
E = E x y z | s | n
```

At this point, you have *direct* left recursion, which is easier to transform. When you deal with that, the result would be something like this -- in pseudo EBNF:

```
E = (s | n) (x y z)*
```

In your case, the definition of `Expr` would become:

```
Expr = (string | name) Args*
Args = "(" ExprList? ")"
ExprList = Expr ("," Expr)*
```