# ANTLR4 Lexing C++11 Raw String

Tags: c++, c++11, antlr, antlr4, lexer

All,

I been playing around with creating a C++ grammar from the Standards document N4567, which is the latest I could find.  I believe the grammar is complete, but I need to test it.  One issue I been trying to resolve is to have the lexer recognize Raw Strings from the standard.  I've implemented a possible solution using Actions & Semantic Predicates.  I need help determining if it actually works. I've read the ANTLR4 Reference on the interaction between Actions and Predicates but can decide if my solution is valid.  A strip down grammar is included below.  Any thoughts will be appreciated.  I've tried to include my thoughts in the sample.

```
grammar SampleRaw;

@lexer::members {
    string d_char_seq = "";
}

string_literal
        : ENCODING_PREFIX? '\"' S_CHAR* '\"'
        | ENCODING_PREFIX? 'R' Raw_String
        ;

ENCODING_PREFIX             //  one of
        : 'u8'
        | [uUL]
        ;

S_CHAR          /* any member of the source character set except the
                   double_quote ", backslash \, or NEW_LINE character
                 */
        : ~[\"\\\n\r]
        | ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
        | UNIV_CHAR_NAME
        ;

fragment ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
        : SIMPLE_ESCAPE_SEQ
        | OCT_ESCAPE_SEQ
        | HEX_ESCAPE_SEQ
        ;
fragment SIMPLE_ESCAPE_SEQ  // one of
        : '\\' '\''
        | '\\' '\"'
        | '\\' '?'
        | '\\' '\\'
        | '\\' 'a'
        | '\\' 'b'
        | '\\' 'f'
        | '\\' 'n'
        | '\\' 'r'
        | '\\' 't'
        | '\\' 'v'
        ;
fragment OCT_ESCAPE_SEQ
        : [0-3] ( OCT_DIGIT OCT_DIGIT? )?
        | [4-7] ( OCT_DIGIT )?
        ;
fragment HEX_ESCAPE_SEQ
        : '\\' 'x' HEX_DIGIT+
        ;
fragment UNIV_CHAR_NAME
        : '\\' 'u' HEX_QUAD
        | '\\' 'U' HEX_QUAD HEX_QUAD
        ;
fragment HEX_QUAD
        : HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
        ;
fragment HEX_DIGIT
        : [a-zA-Z0-9]
        ;
fragment OCT_DIGIT
        : [0-7]
        ;
/*
Raw_String
        : '\"' D_CHAR* '(' R_CHAR* ')' D_CHAR* '\"'
        ;
 */

Raw_String
        : ( /* CASE when D_CHAR is empty
               ACTION in D_CHAR_SEQ attempts to reset variable d_char_seq
               if it is empty, so handle it staticly
             */
            '\"' 
                '('
                    ( ~[)]       // Anything but )
                    | [)] ~[\"]  // ) Actually OK, can't be followed by "
                                 //  - )" - these are the terminating chars
                    )* 
                ')' 
            '\"'
          | '\"'
                D_CHAR_SEQ  /* Will the ACTION in D_CHAR_SEQ be an issue for
                               the Semantic Predicates Below????
                             */
                    '('
                        ( ~[)]  // Anything but )
                        | [)] D_CHAR_SEQ { ( getText() !=  d_char_seq ) }?
                                /* ) Actually OK, can't be followed D_CHAR_SEQ match
                                   IF D_CHAR_SEQs match, turn OFF the Alternative
                                 */
                        | [)] D_CHAR_SEQ { ( getText() ==  d_char_seq ) }? ~[\"]
                                /* ) Actually OK, must be followed D_CHAR_SEQ match
                                     IF D_CHAR_SEQs match, turn ON the Alternative
                                     Cant't match the final " , but
                                     WE HAVE MATCHED OUR TERMINATING CHARS
                                 */
                        )*
                    ')'
                D_CHAR_SEQ /* No need to check here,
                              Matching Terminating CHARS is only way to get out 
                              of loop above
                            */
            '\"'
          )
          { d_char_seq = ""; } // Reset Variable
        ;
/*
fragment R_CHAR
                // any member of the source character set, except a right
                // parenthesis ) followed by the initial D_CHAR*
                // (which may be empty) followed by a double quote ".
                // 
        : ~[)]
        ;
 */

fragment D_CHAR
                /* any member of the basic source character set except
                   space, the left parenthesis (, the right parenthesis ),
                   the backslash \, and the control characters representing
                    horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and newline.
                 */
        : ~[ )(\\\t\v\f\n\r]
        ;
fragment D_CHAR_SEQ
        : D_CHAR+ { d_char_seq = ( d_char_seq == "" ) ? getText() : d_char_seq ; }
        ;
```

Comment: Hope you are just tinkering.  A full C++ parser is actually a *lot* of *tricky* work: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/1004737#1004737.   You know there's already a partial C++ grammar available for ANTLR3?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. A full C++ parser is a lot of work and I may never complete that task.  However a gear head / geek such as myself needs something to do in my down time.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to hack this out myself, any comments or possible improvements would be greatly appreciated.  IF this can be done without ACTIONs that would be great to know as well.

The one draw back is that \" and D_CHAR_SEQ are part of the text of Raw_String passed to the parser.  The parser can strip them out but, it would nice if the lexer did it.

```
grammar SampleRaw;

Reg_String
    : '\"' S_CHAR* '\"'
    ;
fragment S_CHAR
        /* any member of the source character set except the
           double_quote ", backslash \, or NEW_LINE character
         */
    : ~[\n\r\"\\]
    | ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
    | UNIV_CHAR_NAME
    ;
fragment ESCAPE_SEQUENCE
    : SIMPLE_ESCAPE_SEQ
    | OCT_ESCAPE_SEQ
    | HEX_ESCAPE_SEQ
    ;
fragment SIMPLE_ESCAPE_SEQ  // one of
    : '\\' '\''
    | '\\' '\"'
    | '\\' '?'
    | '\\' '\\'
    | '\\' 'a'
    | '\\' 'b'
    | '\\' 'f'
    | '\\' 'n'
    | '\\' 'r'
    | '\\' 't'
    | '\\' 'v'
    ;
fragment OCT_ESCAPE_SEQ
    : [0-3] ( OCT_DIGIT OCT_DIGIT? )?
    | [4-7] ( OCT_DIGIT )?
    ;
fragment OCT_DIGIT
    : [0-7]
    ;
fragment HEX_ESCAPE_SEQ
    : '\\' 'x' HEX_DIGIT+
    ;
fragment HEX_DIGIT
    : [a-zA-Z0-9]
    ;
fragment UNIV_CHAR_NAME
    : '\\' 'u' HEX_QUAD
    | '\\' 'U' HEX_QUAD HEX_QUAD
    ;
fragment HEX_QUAD
    : HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

Raw_String
    : 'R'
      '\"'              // Match Opening Double Quote
      ( /* Handle Empty D_CHAR_SEQ without Predicates
           This should also work
           '(' .*? ')'
         */
        '(' ( ~')' | ')'+ ~'\"' )* (')'+)

      | D_CHAR_SEQ
            /*  // Limit D_CHAR_SEQ to 16 characters
               { ( ( getText().length() - ( getText().indexOf("\"") + 1 ) ) <= 16 ) }?
            */
        '('
        /* From Spec :
           Any member of the source character set, except
           a right parenthesis ) followed by the initial D_CHAR_SEQUENCE
           ( which may be empty ) followed by a double quote ".

         - The following loop consumes characters until it matches the
           terminating sequence of characters for the RAW STRING
         - The options are mutually exclusive, so Only one will
           ever execute in each loop pass
         - Each Option will execute at least once.  The first option needs to
           match the ')' character even if the D_CHAR_SEQ is empty. The second
           option needs to match the closing \" to fall out of the loop. Each
           option will only consume at most 1 character
         */
        (   //  Consume everthing but the Double Quote
          ~'\"'
        |   //  If text Does Not End with closing Delimiter, consume the Double Quote
          '\"'
          {
               !getText().endsWith(
                    ")"
                  + getText().substring( getText().indexOf( "\"" ) + 1
                                       , getText().indexOf( "(" )
                                       )
                  + '\"'
                )
          }?
        )*
      )
      '\"'              // Match Closing Double Quote

      /*
      // Strip Away R"D_CHAR_SEQ(...)D_CHAR_SEQ"
      //  Send D_CHAR_SEQ <TAB> ... to Parser
      {
        setText( getText().substring( getText().indexOf("\"") + 1
                                    , getText().indexOf("(")
                                    )
               + "\t"
               + getText().substring( getText().indexOf("(") + 1
                                    , getText().lastIndexOf(")")
                                    )
               );
      }
       */
    ;
fragment D_CHAR_SEQ     // Should be limited to 16 characters
    : D_CHAR+
    ;
fragment D_CHAR
        /*  Any member of the basic source character set except
            space, the left parenthesis (, the right parenthesis ),
            the backslash \, and the control characters representing
            horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and newline.
         */
    : '\u0021'..'\u0023'
    | '\u0025'..'\u0027'
    | '\u002a'..'\u003f'
    | '\u0041'..'\u005b'
    | '\u005d'..'\u005f'
    | '\u0061'..'\u007e'
    ;
ENCODING_PREFIX         //  one of
    : 'u8'
    | [uUL]
    ;
WhiteSpace
    : [ \u0000-\u0020\u007f]+ -> skip
    ;
start
    : string_literal* EOF
    ;
string_literal
    : ENCODING_PREFIX? Reg_String
    | ENCODING_PREFIX? Raw_String
    ;
```